# How do I sort associations (on field or custom field)

Tags: sorting, entity, associations, criteria, shopware

I've got the following code for automatically loading `streams` (dynamic product groups) with all products, but I would like to sort them based on a custom field.

```
public function search(Criteria $criteria, SalesChannelContext $salesChannelContext): EntitySearchResult
{
    $criteria->addAssociation('streams');

    return $this->decorated->search($criteria, $salesChannelContext);
}
```

How can I sort the results using `$criteria` (meaning through SQL), or do I have to sort it using standard PHP after getting the results?

Comment: I think you need to sort that in PHP cause custom_fields in SQL are just some JSON representation of all custom_field values in one field

Answer (score 2):

Associations allow passing of sorting information and additional filters, too:

```
public function search(Criteria $criteria, SalesChannelContext $salesChannelContext): EntitySearchResult
{
    $criteria->addAssociation('streams');
    $criteria->getAssociation('streams')
        ->addSorting(new FieldSorting('createdAt', FieldSorting::DESCENDING))
        ->addFilter(new NotFilter(NotFilter::CONNECTION_AND, [new EqualsFilter('id', 'c0aeba4aff28462db3ef3880514fe62d')]);

    return $this->decorated->search($criteria, $salesChannelContext);
}
```

If the association is not present during the `getAssociation()` call, it will be added automatically. You can therefore omit the `addAssociation()` call completely.

Sorting and filtering via PHP is always a good backup tough :)